# A value for the key “WKApplication“, or WKWatchKitApp if your project has a WatchKit App Extension target, is required in Runner.app/Runner.app bundle

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, xcode9.3

App Store Connect Operation Failed
Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key “WKApplication“, or “WKWatchKitApp“ if your project has a WatchKit App Extension target, is required in “Runner.app/Runner.app“ bundle. For details, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/creating_independent_watchos_apps/setting_up_a_watchos_project With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90906 for id e981e416-dc00-41ca-8442-ed1ffb0a8f79

Also Using the Transporter App

[[image: Transporter ScreenShotFROM XCODE after Clicking Distribute App]

Comment: Hey Buchi Emmanuel, I just got the same error. I tried to upload my flutter app with a companion watch app to Apple Store Connect. I got the Error while validating my archive. Did you find a solution for that problem?