# Flutter - Apple Watch - unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension' for platform 'iphoneos'

Tags: flutter, apple-watch, flutter-ios

I try to create a Flutter app with android and apple watch support.
For android i don't have problems so far. But I'm struggling with apple watch.

I followed the official instruction from flutter: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/ios/apple-watch. If I see it right, we don't have to enable Bitcode anymore because since Xcode 14 Bitcode is deprecated.
But anyway, i tried it with enabling and without enabling Bitcode. Both ways run into the same error.

After I added the Watch App as a Target I get these Errors:

> Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
>
> Error (Xcode): unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension' for platform 'iphoneos'
>
> Error (Xcode): Couldn't look up product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension' in domain 'iphoneos': Couldn't load spec with identifier 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension' in domain 'iphoneos'
>
> Error (Xcode): unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2' for platform 'iphoneos'
>
> Error (Xcode): Couldn't look up product type 'com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2' in domain 'iphoneos': Couldn't load spec with identifier 'com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2' in domain 'iphoneos'

[image]

Googleing this errors leaded me to this stackoverflow question and answer from 'karim'.

[target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632660/target-specifies-product-type-com-apple-product-type-watchkit2-extension-but)

> In my case, most of the things were ok when I add watchkit extension with xcode 7. but debug target of the extension was iOS. So when I run in debug/simulator I got this error. I have to change them to WatchOS. and Solved. Select Project > Targets > Supported Platform > Debug > watchOS (I had iOS here).

Checking my Supported Platforms, i saw that for my watch targets at 'Supported Platforms' it was also 'watchOS' for 'Debug' but for 'Profile' and 'Release' it was 'iphoneos'

[image]

I changed 'Profile' and 'Release' to 'watchOS'. Running with this changes, i get only three of the previous errors:

> Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
>
> Error (Xcode): unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension' for platform 'iphoneos'
>
> Error (Xcode): unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2' for platform 'iphoneos'
>
> Error (Xcode): Couldn't look up product type 'com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2' in domain 'iphoneos': Couldn't load spec with identifier 'com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2' in domain 'iphoneos'

[image]

And at this point, I stuck... I don't know how to continue.

I found this guide and example that runs fine. But flutter shows an warning that parts of the code are already deprecated. I can't figure out what are the differences that makes his project run and my is having problems with...

https://medium.com/kbtg-life/adding-apple-watch-to-flutter-app-via-flutter-method-channel-f1443532d94e

https://github.com/theamorn/flutter-apple-watch

Can someone help?
Thanks in advance! :)

### Edit 1 - 19.9.2022

Okay, the code of the example I talked about above, is not deprecated, just needs a small migration.
The original warning was:

> This app is using a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
>
> To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future building failures, try to migrate this app to the V2 embedding.
>
> Take a look at the docs for migrating an app: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects
> [image]

What I just needed to do was to change in the AndroidMainifest.xml:

> <application
> android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"

to:

> <application
> android:name="${applicationName}"

like here described:
[How to Fix Flutter Warning: Your Flutter application is created using an older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425132/how-to-fix-flutter-warning-your-flutter-application-is-created-using-an-older-v)

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

But that still doesn't solve my original problem.
I don't want to build my app based of the example project. I would like to start at an entire new flutter project and add a Apple Watch as target.
I still can't figure out what are the differences between a new created project based on the flutter instruction and the working example project...

### Edit 2 - 20.9.2022

Thanks to the Answer of @Einzeln , I noticed that my config ui layout looks different to his.
So I checked for Updates on all Programms that are needed.

Just for clarification what I have installed now after the update:

- Flutter 3.3.2 - channel stable
- Dart 2.18.1
- DevTools 2.15.0
- Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1
- Xcode Version 14.0

First different that I notice is that the file structure is different if I add a watch as target:
[image]
There is only on directory for the watch and not like before I updated ,and also in the example that I talked earlier, that there were two directory. One labeled 'watch' and the other 'watch extension'.

Thanks to @Einzelns answer  I also checked the configuration. I had to manually add the watch to my 'Runner' app at 'Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content'.
[image]
At the 'watch' I didn't need to add the Runner app there.
[image]
But I had to add the 'WatchKit Companion App Bundle Identifier' for the 'watch' at Build Settings -> Info.plist Values.
[image]

Starting both apps (watch app and smartphone app) from Xcode is working without any problems.

But starting the Flutter Project / App form Android Studio and also from terminal with 'flutter run' or 'flutter run --release' is leading me to this following problem:

[image]

Why is it working fine starting from Xcode but has problems starting from flutter?
For me it seems like that the default generated watch app has code that is only available at iOS 14 and newer. Here is the generated default code:

[image]

[image]

But probably I can work from here on and 'just' need to recreate the code so, that it is also supported by older iOS versions.

Comment: I use SwiftUI in my tutorial but SwiftUI need iOS13 or later to make it work. You might need to update project setting to support SwiftUI which is iOS 13. Otherwise, you could work with Storyboard instead. When you add new extension, it will ask you that what type of layout that you’re going to use for.

Comment: Since the Xcode update that I described under "Edit 2", i can't select a layout anymore. Seems like SwiftUI is now default.
But thank you a lot for your support. I'm at a point now from where I can continue to work.

I just tried to test upload my flutter app and got the same validation error like here asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72620278/a-value-for-the-key-wkapplication-or-wkwatchkitapp-if-your-project-has-a-watc

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I have no idea what's happening with your project but I guess it's about Xcode configurations.

Can you check in Xcode > Targets > General
and see if you don't miss importing any Watch app inside

iOS
[image]

Apple Watch
[image]

Comment: thank you for your response! That helped me to get forward with my problems :D But now I think I'm at a point from where on I can work.
I added all my new knowledge to my original post.

Answer (score 2):

Change supported platforms in build setting to watchOS.

[WatchOS Target Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOZXn.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This fixed it for me, hopefully the supporting image from @icearea remains for future generations! If not .. Watch target -> Build Settings -> Supported Platforms make sure your Watch App has WatchOS selected. Mine was iOS (default I presume) and broke during upload. Runner remains on iOS obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue recently. I tried all the above solutions but got no effect. I found this one when I'm about to give up: https://dev.to/gie3d/add-an-apple-watch-target-on-flutter-app-3m0m

By updating the `WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier` to the `info.plist` in the WatchKit Extension folder, all the problems went away, and I can compile the app again.

```
<!-- `info.plist` in WatchKit Extension folder -->
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        ....blablabla
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.watchkit</string>
    </dict>

    <!-- Add the following two lines -->
    <key>WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>

</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are two main problems you are facing:**

1. **Lack of Apple's up-to-date documentation** after they changed watchOS project structure and moved watchOS App target settings to the main project file.
2. **bugs in xCode** that don't allow you to setup you project correctly.

I have recently spent **a week** setting up a similar project and here's  how I got it going:

1. **Downgrade your xCode** to [late 2021/early 2022](https://xcodereleases.com/) [!!!critical step!!!]
2. **Create Flutter project** as usual (`flutter create ...`)
3. **Add watchOS companion app** as per every [manual](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/setting_up_a_watchos_project) out there (File->New->Target->watchOS-> add WatchOS Companion app ), and make sure it still runs as expected
4. **Merge your project with** [Apple Watch Conectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity) code sample by manually dragging the watch App and extension files from finder into the xCode project, making sure your targets are assigned correctly. Make sure to manually merge the code of the `AppDelegate.swift` files. **The trick here is to [keep the Watch app's Info.plist file](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92294#issuecomment-1003247676) from the code sample, but exclude it from the xCode build phases [!!! critical step !!!]**
5. **Upgrade xCode back to latest**
6. **Update your bundle ID's** in all three targets' `Info.plist` files as/if necessary
7. Make sure your project still runs and back it up
8. **Upgrade your xCode project** as per xCode's suggestion - it will remove one of the targets so you will only have two, not three.
9. If everything went well - now you should be able to run the watch app with Flutter app.
10. **Add Native Channel** to Flutter app and iOS app to port connectivity status and other events in and out of Flutter app.
11. **Run watchOS target** via xCode and minimize it (do not close!).
12. **Run flutter debug** as per usual.

Now you should end up with your Flutter debug session connected to the watch app and you can use hot reload etc. to develop your FLutter app as per usual.