# Flutter iOS Validation -A value for the key “WKApplication“, or “WKWatchKitApp“ if your project has a WatchKit App Extension target, is required

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, apple-watch, flutter-ios

I working on a flutter app that interacts with a similar smaller version as watch app.
For Android I'm not faceing probelms. But I'm still struggling with iOS.
After I created the default flutter app and added a watch as target, I tried to test validate this. I archived my project with

> flutter build ipa

and validated the created archive. For that I opened

> My App > build > ios > archive > Runner.xcarchive

by double clicking on it. That opend Xcode and the 'archive manager'. Here I clicked on 'Validate'.
I also tried it by the 'Transproter' app.

Both validation ways are ending with this error:

> Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key “WKApplication“, or “WKWatchKitApp“ if your project has a WatchKit App Extension target, is required in “Runner.app/Watch/XXXXX App.app“ bundle. For details, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/creating_independent_watchos_apps/setting_up_a_watchos_project

[image: Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key “WKApplication“, or “WKWatchKitApp“ if your project has a WatchKit App Extension target, is required in “Runner.app/Watch/XXXXX App.app“ bundle.]

I have no idea how I can fix this.
My current setup is:

- Flutter 3.3.2 - channel stable
- Dart 2.18.1
- DevTools 2.15.0
- Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1
- Xcode Version 14.0

What I also tried is: I created a new project with a normal iOS App (not flutter) and added a watch as target. This validated without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue when I want to archive and release a test version of my flutter project with a watch app in Xcode 14. I can run the whole project locally without any problem. I have no idea how to deal with it so far.

I tried to add the `WKWatchKitApp` key to the `info.plist` of the WatchKit App, but I got more errors saying that I'm missing the WatchKit App Extension' target. I'm confused about it since the [Xcode 14 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes) said:

> Xcode 14 includes a default template for watchOS apps that **combines the WatchKit App and WatchKit App Extension targets into a single Watch App target**, simplifying code, asset, and localization management. You can deploy single-target watchOS apps to watchOS 7 and later. (83222217)

I'm developing with:

- Flutter 3.3.0
- Dart 2.18.0
- DevTools 2.15.0
- Xcode 14.0

I'm wondering if it is caused by Xcode or the old version of Flutter.

### Update: 20230211

I tried to upgrade my Flutter to `3.7.3`, delete the build cache by running `flutter clean`, and clean the Xcode build folder. Then update and reinstall all the flutter and pod dependencies I'm using and recompile the whole project. The project can now archive and release to Testflight.

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked on flutter in combination with the apple Watch. At the end I could get them connected. I'm not sure if I documented everything completely but I tried to keep track of my attempts in this question. Maybe that will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73770044/flutter-apple-watch-unable-to-resolve-product-type-com-apple-product-type-w

Comment: Actually, I replied with a solution to that article you posted when I faced the same issue. The connection between the Flutter and watch parts is fine after the discussion you raised, thanks.